# Getting Error when passing image inside Firebase notification

Tags: android, image, firebase, android-bitmap, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to pass image inside the FireBase Notification  but it is showing me error for parsing the json object 
bellow is the log cat that shows the error[image]

this is the json that send the data from server

```
{"to":"dJ4ege8LbI8:APA91bGqGQyIEBn2TsSnb7yZjv-2RjRCK8L1mqzxDnP0_lJBDvAPu7QzF7SVmb_gBmpo2n7w97B9mPjHpDOdDaPb-CDhngKZMOO4Xc79lrhTImsuVicf2mZOquVkhHq1JBR-KAcLf-9F","notification":{"body":"gdshgh","title":"jkhds","icon":"myicon","sound":"mysound","click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY"},"data":{"image":"http://www.propertynewsindia.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Buy-A-New-Home.jpg"}}
```

which is a valid json output
please help Thanks in Advance...

MyFirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
NotificationUtils notificationUtils;
String imageUrl;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated.
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            handleDataMessage(json);
        }catch (JSONException je){
            Log.e(TAG,"JSONException: "+je.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("test")
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)     getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
private void handleNotification(String message) {
    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

        // play notification sound
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        notificationUtils.getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);
    }else{
        // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
    }
}

private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
    Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");
        boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
        String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
        String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
        JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

        Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
        Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
        Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
        Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
        Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
        Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the` push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

            // check for image attachment
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
            } else {
                // image is present, show notification with image
                showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Showing notification with text only
 */
private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
}

/**
 * Showing notification with text and image
 */
private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
}
```

}

NotificationUtills

```
public class NotificationUtils {
private static String TAG = NotificationUtils.class.getSimpleName();

private Context mContext;

public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, null);
}

public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    // Check for empty push message
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
        return;


    // notification icon
    final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    mContext,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );

    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            mContext);

    final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
            + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

        if (imageUrl != null && imageUrl.length() > 4 && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(imageUrl).matches()) {

            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);

            if (bitmap != null) {
                showBigNotification(bitmap, mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            } else {
                showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            }
        }
    } else {
        showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
        playNotificationSound();
    }
}


private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

    inboxStyle.addLine(message);

    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}

private void showBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {
    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
    bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
    bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
    bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE, notification);
}

/**
 * Downloading push notification image before displaying it in
 * the notification tray
 */
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        Log.i("URL-IMAGE",strURL);
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

// Playing notification sound
public void playNotificationSound() {
    try {
        Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, alarmSound);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Method checks if the app is in background or not
 */
public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            isInBackground = false;
        }
    }

    return isInBackground;
}

// Clears notification tray messages
public static void clearNotifications(Context context) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}

public static long getTimeMilliSec(String timeStamp) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(timeStamp);
        return date.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

[image: this is the new error i'm receving after the changes.....]

Comment: what does that means??? i didn't understand because i'm giving audio sound to the notification and that sound is been working properly

Comment: are you passing just url OR whole payload as url to getBitmapFromUrl method?

Comment: I'm passing only url and not all the values

Comment: print that in this method, what you are receiving.

Comment: Please tell me then what parameters should i pass do i have to pass all the parameters????? to get the right output???? Anyhow Thanks for your relay...

Comment: @UsmanRana Ok let me see that

Comment: look JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            String title = data.getString("title");
            String message = data.getString("message");
            boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
            String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
            String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
            JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload"); these are the parameters that i needed

Comment: @SnehalGongle please check this link [firebase-push-notification-android-with-image](http://androidbash.com/firebase-push-notification-android/)

Comment: the issue in parsing of data. In getBitmapFromUrl  method you print Logs that waht url are you using to download bitmap

Comment: which i'm not sure about is the "is_background"

Comment: and share the code of onMessageReceived function. The issue is in handling and parsing of data.

Comment: if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
 

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            }catch (JSONException je){
                Log.e(TAG,"JSONException: "+je.getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

Comment: @usmanRana where remoteMessage is the output and handleDataMessage handles the json that is coming from server

Comment: Edit your question and paste full code of Notification utils and MyFirebaseService. In comments code can't be read properly

Comment: @UsmanRana I have edited my question and pasted the complete files please check the changes Thanks for all the help.....

Comment: the jos that you are passing to handleDataMessage has only 1 value . "image" . use String imageUrl = json.getString("image"); , all other are not available in your payload so these are null

Comment: @UsmanRana what is payload what should it be????

Comment: You are sending only "image" value in object "data":{"image":"http://www.propertynewsindia.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Buy-A-New-Home.jpg"}
. but in app you are getting more from it , which is causing issue

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are sending only 1 vale "image" in notification data but reading other values as well which are missing in it,send json as following with all values that you want to read in app:

```
{
   {
   "to":"dJ4ege8LbI8:APA91bGqGQyIEBn2TsSnb7yZjv-2RjRCK8L1mqzxDnP0_lJBDvAPu7QzF7SVmb_gBmpo2n7w97B9mPjHpDOdDaPb-CDhngKZMOO4Xc79lrhTImsuVicf2mZOquVkhHq1JBR-KAcLf-9F",
   "notification":{  
      "body":"gdshgh",
      "title":"jkhds",
      "icon":"myicon",
      "sound":"mysound",
      "click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY"
   },
   "data":{  
      "data":{  
         "image":"http://www.propertynewsindia.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Buy-A-New-Home.jpg"
      },
      "title":"My title",
      "message":"My message",
      "is_background":true,
      "timestamp:"2017-07-31 05:42:12",
      "payload":{  
         "name":"Test"
      }
   }
}
```

And parse the code data as following:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
NotificationUtils notificationUtils;
String imageUrl;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated.
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null && remoteMessage.getData().size()==0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    else if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().getString("data"));
            handleDataMessage(json);
        }catch (JSONException je){
            Log.e(TAG,"JSONException: "+je.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("test")
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)     getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
private void handleNotification(String message) {
    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

        // play notification sound
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
    }else{
        // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
    }
}

private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
    Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

    try {

        String title = json.getString("title");
        String message = json.getString("message");
        boolean isBackground = json.getBoolean("is_background");
        String imageUrl = json.getString("image");
        String timestamp = json.getString("timestamp");
        JSONObject payload = json.getJSONObject("payload");

        Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
        Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
        Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
        Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
        Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
        Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the` push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

            // check for image attachment
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
            } else {
                // image is present, show notification with image
                showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Showing notification with text only
 */
private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
}

/**
 * Showing notification with text and image
 */
private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
}
```

Comment: {"to":"dJ4ege8LbI8:APA91bGqGQyIEBn2TsSnb7yZjv-2RjRCK8L1mqzxDnP0_lJBDvAPu7QzF7SVmb_gBmpo2n7w97B9mPjHpDOdDaPb-CDhngKZMOO4Xc79lrhTImsuVicf2mZOquVkhHq1JBR-KAcLf-9F","notification":{"body":"jhdjsj","title":"jhgfdj","icon":"myicon","click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY"},"data":{"image":"http://www.propertynewsindia.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Buy-A-New-Home.jpg","title":"my title","message":"my message","is_background":true,"timestamp":"2017-07-31 05:42:12","payload":{"title":"jhgfdj"}}}

Comment: i got this json output and my appliction got terminated    with  java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message  at public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
        try {
            Log.i("URL-IMAGE",strURL);

Comment: i've changed the code for more ease to you. Use the updated code now

Comment: i have changed the code accordingly and i got a diffrent error i have edited my question please check the newly added image Thanks  for the help....

Comment: paste your "Data Payload" string here

Comment: Data Payload: {payload={"name":"snehal"}, timestamp=2017-07-31 05:42:12, image=http://www.propertynewsindia.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Buy-A-New-Home.jpg, title=my title, message=my message, is_background=true}

Comment: JSONException: Unterminated object at character 50 of {payload={"name":"snehal"}, timestamp=2017-07-31 05:42:12, image=http://www.propertynewsindia.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Buy-A-New-Home.jpg, title=my title, message=my message, is_background=true}